# Ubuntu live USB boots into BusyBox shell

Tags: boot, usb, busybox

My apologies if this is a duplicate, but I'm in a fix.

Some problems happened, and my linux was erased from harddrive. I tried to install Fedora / Ubuntu 16, but when trying to boot a live system from USB, it shows the purple splash screen with cycling dots for a while and then boots into BusyBox shell instead of Ubuntu.

But Puppy linux works, and I'm writing this from there.

(My computer is HP Pavillion.)

Currently my harddrive looks like this from GParted on puppy.

[My harddrive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgzz0.png)

If I can't even live boot Ubuntu I can't install it, or use my laptop.
I have puppy linux on my usb now, and it works, but how do I fix this?

(If you need any information that can be obtained from within Puppy, I'll post it if you ask for it)

Thanks!

Comment: You have to describe in more detail what happens when you try to boot the Ubuntu live system/installer. The HDD is unlikely to be the problem, out of the blue I'd rather guess on the graphics hardware being not compatible out of the box maybe. What graphics card do you have?

Comment: Sorry for not describing that earlier. Whenever I'm inserting and booting Ubuntu, the ubuntu splash screen appears fine, (the one with "ubuntu" written, with dots below it, that change colors). I press a key to see the log during boot. For a long time nothing appears. Then after a while, it drops me into Busybox shell. Following that I've no option but to halt the system.